# Using the append to print out to a textArea from a list

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, jtextfield

So, from my previous question I decided to go ahead and use the list as recommended (Thank you for that).

I've got a single class now that uses a list. This list is updated through the button. When a user presses on the button, values within the textfield are parsed to double and saved into the list. I am trying to create a method to be placed into the button that will print out the list.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class foodDept extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    ArrayList<MyShoppingCart> list = new ArrayList<MyShoppingCart>();

    public foodDept() {
        initComponents();
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        appleLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        cartArea = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        appleField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        bananaField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        addTocart = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        appleLabel.setText("Apple ($1.99):");

        cartArea.setColumns(20);
        cartArea.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(cartArea);
        cartArea.setEditable(false);

        jLabel1.setText("Banana ($0.99):");

        addTocart.setText("Add to Cart");
        addTocart.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                addTocartActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(appleLabel)
                        .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addComponent(appleField)
                                .addGap(44, 44, 44))
                            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                    .addComponent(addTocart)
                                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                                        .addComponent(bananaField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                                        .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 35, Short.MAX_VALUE)))
                        .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addComponent(appleLabel)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addComponent(appleField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addGap(21, 21, 21)
                        .addComponent(jLabel1)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                        .addComponent(bananaField, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 96, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(addTocart))
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1))
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
   **// HEEEEEEERRRRRRRRRRRREEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE
    void printList() {
        cartArea.setText("");
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){
            cartArea.append(list[i].toString());
        }//******** ^ THIS IS THE METHOD IM TALKING ABOUT (printList)^*******
    }**

    **private void addTocartActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
       double a = Double.parseDouble(appleField.getText());
       list.add(new MyShoppingCart(a));
       double b = Double.parseDouble(bananaField.getText());
       list.add(new MyShoppingCart(b));
       appleField.setText("");
       bananaField.setText("");
       printList();
    } //where the values are parsed**                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(foodDept.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(foodDept.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(foodDept.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(foodDept.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new foodDept().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton addTocart;
    private javax.swing.JTextField appleField;
    private javax.swing.JLabel appleLabel;
    private javax.swing.JTextField bananaField;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea cartArea;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You try to use `List` as an `Array`, but it's wrong.

Use next:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        cartArea.append(list.get(i).toString());
  }
```

`list.size()` like a `array.length`

and `list.get(i)` as `array[i]`

Read [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/list.html) for `List`.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Alex. I'll have a look through.